# How can three divs expand the parent element when only the middle div has a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have three div elements expand the width of the parent while only the middle div has a fixed width? The div element to the left and right of the middle one should have equal widths.

I want something like this to work:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div id="elasticWidth1"></div>
    <div id="fixedWidth"></div>
    <div id="elasticWidth2"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: This is what the result should look like:
[image]

Comment: All the 3 divs has equal width means, fixed width doesn't make any sense. All the 3 divs should be 33.33%

Comment: @tundoopani can you post the image of your desired result.....

Comment: what is your fixed width and can you change the structure of the html?

Comment: @ShailenderArora I added the image to the question.

Comment: @Sowmya I have not said that the three widths are equal.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Urbrf/6/

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="halfWidth left">
        <div class="padding">
            <div id="columnOne" class="fullWidth">
            </div>
            <div id="columnTwo" class="fixedWidth">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="halfWidth right">
        <div class="padding">
            <div id="columnThree" class="fullWidth">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {width:100%;}
.halfWidth {width:50%;}
.fullWidth {width:100%;}
.left,
.left .fullWidth {float:left;}
.left .padding {padding-right:100px;} /*half of the fixed width*/
.right,
.right .fullWidth {float:right;}
.right .padding {padding-left:100px;} /*half of the fixed width*/

.fixedWidth {width:200px; margin-right:-200px; float:right;}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work great. I tried to figure out how to remove some nesting by using box-sizing: http://jsfiddle.net/tsk5X/. It seems to do the same thing.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure on your compatibility to use box-sizing so I thought I'd give you the more compatible version

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it with float, I would do it with inline-block:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Anyway, how do you want to set the width of the left & right-div equaly, when they are elastic?